# Merge Dataframes Based on Time

Tags: python, pandas

I've got a high density data set with timestamps I'll call `df1`, and a low density data set with start and end datetimes for tickets I'll call `df2`.

How can I merge a start datetime, end datetime, and ticket id from `df2` onto `df1`?

For now, I'm cross joining the data and filtering when the timestamp is between the start and end datetime. I know cross joins are horrible for performance, but I'm not sure how to do this otherwise. How can I do this more performantly?

```
df_merge = df1.merge(df2[['StartDT', 'EndDT', 'TicketID']], how='cross')
df_out = df_merge[df_merge['Timestamp'].between(df_merge['StartDT'], df_merge['EndDT'])]
```

I then group and aggregate the data for summarization.